# send javascript variable into html selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to send my variable: `username` into my selector (display username in my selector) and send my variable `userid` as value in my selector.
Can you help me ? Here is my code :

```
<select id="mySecond" name="continent">
    <option value="">-----------------</option>
    <option  value="">-----------------</option>
    </select>


<script>

function displayuser() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Mon id: " + x;

  $.ajax({
      url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/"+x+"/users.json",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
            contentType:'application/json',
            secure: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("claire.pagniez@cubber.com"));
            },
            success: function (data){
                for (i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
                console.log(data.users[i].name);
                var username = data.users[i].name;
                console.log(data.users[i].id);
                var userid = data.users[i].id;
                }
            },
  });
}

</script>
```

Comment: It is difficult to corelate your question to your code. Tell us how do you want username and userid to be used in a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
success: function (data)  {
  $.each(data, function(){
        $("#mySecond").append('<option value="'+ this.userid +'">'+ this.username +'</option>')
   })
}
```

Comment: success: function (data){
    for (i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
     console.log(data.users[i].name);
    var username = data.users[i].name;
    console.log(data.users[i].id);
    var userid = data.users[i].id;

   $("#mySecond").append('<option value="'+ userid +'">'+ username +'</option>')

    }
    },